# Declare and use ad-hoc function in bash in interactive shell

Tags: bash, function

Basically something like

```js
// declare
const my_func = function(param1, param2) { do_stuff(param1, param2) }
// use
my_func('a', 'b');
```

All in current interactive shell without using files

Comment: Nice. Now, please ask your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are defined in the same way in an interactive `bash` shell as in a `bash` shell script.

Taking your example as a starting point:

```bsh
my_func () { do_stuff "$1" "$2"; }
```

You would type that on the command line. Then call that (also on the command line) with

```bsh
my_func 'something' 'something else' 'a third thing'
```

Note that you don't declare the argument list as you would do in a language like C or C++. It's up to the function to make intelligent use of the arguments that it gets (and up to you to document the function's use, would it be used for more serious work later).

This would call `do_stuff` with the first of the three arguments that I passed to `my_func`.

A function that does something *slightly* more interesting:

```bsh
countnames () (
    shopt -s nullglob
    names=( ./* )
    printf 'There are %d visible names in this directory\n' "${#names[@]}"
)
```

There is nothing stopping you from typing that into an interactive `bash` shell.  This would make the `countnames` shell function available in the current shell session. (Note that I'm writing the function body in a sub-shell (`(...)`).  I do this because I want to set the `nullglob` shell option without affecting the shell options set in the calling shell.  The `names` array then also automatically becomes local.)

Testing:

```
$ countnames
There are 0 visible names in this directory
$ touch file{1..32}
$ ls
file1  file12 file15 file18 file20 file23 file26 file29 file31 file5  file8
file10 file13 file16 file19 file21 file24 file27 file3  file32 file6  file9
file11 file14 file17 file2  file22 file25 file28 file30 file4  file7
$ countnames
There are 32 visible names in this directory
```

Or using the `zsh` shell as a more sophisticated helper for this function:

```bsh
countnames () {
    printf 'There are %d visible names in this directory\n' \
        "$(zsh -c 'set -- ./*(N); print $#')"
}
```

To "un-define" (remove) a function, use `unset -f`:

```
$ countnames
There are 3 visible names in this directory
$ unset -f countnames
$ countnames
bash: countnames: command not found
```

Comment: See also `zsh -c '(){print $#} *(N)'` or `ls -1q | wc -l`

Comment: Thanks. Did the same, but, silly me, didn't know that one utterly have to put The Semicolon at the end of the single expression in function.

Comment: @disfated The commands in a  `{ ...; }` group always has to end with a semi-colon, or a newline character.